# Regex expression to allow an apostrophe

Tags: php, regex

I've been looking at all of the other posts regarding this topic but I'm still unable to get my regex expression to allow an apostrophe. I thought the following should work but it keeps giving an error. It does allow all of the other characters, numbers and letters, just not the ' (I need it for words like Mike's )

```
/^([-a-zA-Z\/\-\&\\\?\!\,\.\'\"\s0-9@:=_]{1,1000})$/
```

The regex expression is required for validation of a form and part of the following:

```
public $regex = array ('char' => "/^[a-zA-Z.\s]{0,50}$/", 
                       'misc' => "/^([-a-zA-Z\/\-\&\\\?\!\,\.\'\"\s0-9@:=_]{1,1000})$/");

if(preg_match($this->regex[$validation],$this->filteredValue[$fieldName])) { 
    $this->messageArray[$fieldName] = '<span class="cheers"> &nbsp; Thank You</span>';   
}
```

Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong please?

Comment: what's the regex flavor or language ?   have you tried escaping the `'` by adding a backslash to it ? `\'`

Comment: This is not constructive enough. What are you trying to achieve with this regex? Can you provide some examples?

Comment: It looks like a Perl regex and it does allow an apostrophe (unless you mean one of the "smart quote" thingies, such as U+2018 ("LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK")). You don't say what error you're getting.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy replies.

Comment: Oops. Here's the part I ommitted
The regex expression is required for validation of a form and part of the following

public $regex = array (
'char' => "/^[a-zA-Z.\s]{0,50}$/",
'misc' => "/^([-a-zA-Z\/\-\&\\\?\!\,\.\'\"\s0-9@:=_]{1,1000})$/"
 );

if(preg_match($this->regex[$validation],$this->filteredValue[$fieldName])){
                $this->messageArray[$fieldName] = '<span class="cheers"> &nbsp; Thank You</span>';
        }

Comment: This is the error I get (and only get when using the apostrophe)                                            error: INSERT INTO `tbl_collection` (`title`, `status`, `date`) VALUES ('Grant's test', '2', '1346722172')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's test', '2', '1346722172')' at line 6
J:\xampplite\htdocs\52_Pearl\assets\databaseClass.php45query                           Thanks for all your replies so far

Answer (score 2):

The `\'` should work. I can't say why it does not. I can, however, offer a workaround. You can try to replace the `'` with a hex representation of the same character. instead of using `\'` try to use `\x1b`.

Also, you should move the `\-` to be just a `-` at the end of the `[]`

```
/^([-a-zA-Z\/\&\\\?\!\,\.\x1b\"\s0-9@:=_-]{1,1000})$/
```

And I don't understand what's the `-` at the beginning is...

---

EDIT:
After seeing your last comment regarding the error that you get I can only assume that you have mis-identified the problem that you have. For what I see assume that your regexp is all fine, but you have a problem in your SQL statment as you have not escaped the data.

You should familiraize yourself with [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) and make sure you use it in all your queries. For Example:

```
<?php
// Query
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='%s' AND password='%s'",
            mysql_real_escape_string($user),
            mysql_real_escape_string($password));
mysql_query($query);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion which I tried but still get the error.